# open pdf in iphone webapp

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open a pdf from my JQM webapp. I have tried iframes/embed/object, and none of those work on an iphone like they do on a desktop browser (scrolling, zooming, etc). I have settled with simply opening the pdf via a link `<a href="mypdf.pdf">Link</a>`. This works fine in the standard browser because the user can simply use the browser back button to navigate back to my app.

The issue that I am having, is that when a user saves the page to thier home screen and opens it using the chromeless safari browser, they no longer have the browser back button. I have tried adding `target="_blank"` to the link, but apparently JQM hijacks the link and prevents opening in a new page, and I have been unable to get the hacks to work.

I have also tried pdf.js, but I can't seem to even get that to work as my javascript knowledge is fairly limited, and the examples are pretty advanced. The only tutorial that I found used an old version which I couldn't get to work.

Are there any ways to bypass the JQM in openning a link in a new window (which would in turn open in the mobile safari rather than my chromeless web app), or are there any other suggestions for how to open a pdf from a webapp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just disable the default jQuery Mobile behaviour, by specifying `data-ajax=false`.

For example:

```
<a href="somefile.pdf" data-ajax="false">Link</a>
```

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: I find that I do still need the target="_blank" in there for it to work (JqM 1.3.2), but otherwise great.

Answer (score 0):

For my webApps I used https://docs.google.com/viewer to embed the pdf into my interface.
So, when I navigate the webApp by home screen icon, the app doesn't close when I open the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question: `open pdf in webapp with html5`.

I've tried several solutions: iframe、embed、pdf.js, but none of them is the best solution.

`tips`: iOS 9.x upper, open pdf with iframe only show the first page of the pdf file, and there will be a `<img />` tag in the iframe body when you debug.

util now I still have this troublesome problem, anyone has solution please write your experience here.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue of displaying a pdf inside a div. It's a hybrid mobile app. I have also tried iframe, embed, object and pdfjs. Same issue. In the desktop browser(safari), everything works fine, but on mobile none of them works, except for pdfjs. pdf.js displays the pdf inside the div with all the pages and they are scrollable. But pinch to zoom is not available.